# Basic drupal model / concepts

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-7

I'm migrating a site from a proprietary cms (reddot) to drupal. For all its flaws, reddot has a very simple yet flexible model:

- templates consist of markup with placeholders for variable content
- every piece of content, from a full page, to a shared piece of sidebar content, and even a single image can be built from a template, if an appropriate one exists

My first impression of drupal is: woah, this is complicated! Rather than three simple objects, now i'm dealing with nodes, pages, blocks, regions, views, panels, etc. What is the simplest way to recreate the template/content/placeholder model that i'm familiar with?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Reddot uses a rather well architectured MVC-alike system. In addition, from my limited experience, Reddot follows the *there is only one way to achieve Foo*-philosophy.

Coming to Drupal, especially as a frontend-developer you will be dissapointed, lose a lot of hair and probably curse a few times when you realise everything has to be done all over again.

Coming to Drupal you will love the gigantic amount of (unfortunately unorganised) documenation and its flexibility and enormous amount of new posibilities.

When people come from properly architectured systems into Drupal, I advice them to do one thing: become pragmatism-exstremists. Don't (ever) try to make things proper, clean or well-thought out. You will only be able to do that once you truly grok Drupal. And that only comes with a lot of experience. Just **fiddle untill it works, close the code and never look at it again**.

First thing you will need to learn, is Drupals PHPTemplate engine, which is rather different from Reddots, but has a lot of similarities. Where Reddot uses RenderTags, Drupals PHPTemplate uses plain old PHP.

```
<%!! Context:CurrentPage.Template.Name !!%>
```

becomes

```
<?php print $name ?>
```

And yes, `$name` is entirely globally scoped. Remember? I told you to be a pragmatism-extremist. Don't even think about namespacing, object scoping and such.

Want to know what variables you have available? Just do a `<?php print get_defined_vars() ?>`.

Want new variables in your template? You need to [preprocess](http://drupal.org/node/223430) them.

Want to change, alter, strip or modify existing variables? You either need to [preprocess](http://drupal.org/node/223430), or [template override](http://drupal.org/node/173880) or even write new modules that make new or different variables available? 
Knowing which to choose, when to preprocess, when to create modules, when to override, when to implement [hooks](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--module.inc/group/hooks/6) to alter stuff is experience. 
Drupal has never thought that out clearly, there is no general rule or best practice, other then *the last eleven times that Foo-concept did not work out, maybe Bar proves the best*.

Comment: Well put. Drupal hurts my OOP-programming brain, but I got to let it go! I once read (possibly from Dries himself) that the *code* is not object-oriented, but the *system architecture* is. This was an important distinction, for me. Regarding documentation: I've spent *hours* searching Google and the Drupal API when I started writing modules. Ultimately the most effective method is to dig into its source code. It's tedious; I will often overlook the answer several times, but in the end I understand the system better.

Comment: This is great info, berkes, albeit a little disconcerting! ;) Your first sentence sums it up for me (so far): Drupal feels a little like the perl of CMSs.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal's templates are similar to what you describe of reddot, but there are probably more options and they can be nested. To get a good sense of how the templates work together download the [Theme Developer module](https://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) and watch the associated screencast.

To get a sense of the "placeholders" you can use in a given template, visit the [api.drupal.org](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal) page for the template file or check out this [Drupal 6 Theming Cheat Sheet](http://www.minezone.org/blog/2009/02/04/drupal-6-theming-cheat-sheet/).

Comment: I'll check out the screen cast - thanks for the tip. My biggest issue is a lack of understanding around templates. Do they apply to nodes, pages, or blocks? And are they driven by content type?

Comment: There is a page.tpl.php template that is the main default parent template for all content. The node.tpl.php controls the content area. Blocks have their own templates. Templates can be overridden completely or selectively based on"suggestions":  http://drupal.org/node/190815

Comment: They can apply to anything. There is for example node.tpl.php, which is used to render a node. That can be overriden for a specific content-type, for example node-page.tpl.php. See http://drupal.org/documentation/theme for more information about theming in general. http://drupal.org/getting-started/before/overview also looks like it could be of interest to you

Answer (score 1):

Another one bites the dust.. ;)
Let me know how you go with the migration Bobby Jack.
I think for the content you might be able to create an XML variant in the CMS and export everything to re-import it to Drupal..
On the Drupal note: Once you get your head around the concept of templates being able to inherit/being overwritten it's easy.
It's like a set of pre-assigned content classes in RedDot which can change to render them in a different layout. Similar to the "replace content-class" functionality.